# Mix APIView and FormMixin: 'function' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to make a class based view that has GET method which renders a form and POST method which process form data and also accept JSON. So I use Django REST Framework's APIView and Django's FormMixin like this:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from feedback.models import Feedback

class FeedbackView(GenericAPIView, FormMixin):
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer)
    template_name = 'feedback/feedback.html'
    form_class = FeedbackForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('feedback')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        return Response({'form': form})
```

When `get` method is called, I get this error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError at /feedback/
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/roman/.virtualenvs/env__gvis_website/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/roman/.virtualenvs/env__gvis_website/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/roman/.virtualenvs/env__gvis_website/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/roman/.virtualenvs/env__gvis_website/lib/python3.3/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/roman/.virtualenvs/env__gvis_website/lib/python3.3/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/roman/work/gvis_website/feedback/views.py" in get
  62.         form = self.get_form()
File "/home/roman/.virtualenvs/env__gvis_website/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form
  74.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
File "/home/roman/.virtualenvs/env__gvis_website/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form_kwargs
  81.             'initial': self.get_initial(),
File "/home/roman/.virtualenvs/env__gvis_website/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_initial
  54.         return self.initial.copy()
```

`initial` is an empty dictionary defined in FormMixin class like this:

```
initial = {}
```

Why it suddenly lost its `copy` method? Or what does exception means?
Exception won't appear if I replace `APIView` by some Django built-in class like `View`.
Can I use APIView class and FormMixin or I should change my way to render form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is that `GenericAPIView` already has a method called `initial`.

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L369

First thing's first - you should not add FormMixin into DRF generic view, they are not intended to work together. You should use `HTMLFormRenderer` as your renderer instead. Please refer to http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-forms for more details.

Also, think about splitting your json endpoints by using prefixed urls, smth like `api/v1/`. This will save you a lots of headaches overtime, when dealing with more complicated logic.

Comment: Docs say that `HTMLFormRenderer` is not intended to be used directly, but through `render_form ` template tag. I discovered that this tag is not presented in DRF 3.2.3, but there are undocumented `render_field` tag. It doesn't matter though, I'll rather use Django built-in tools for form rendering.
But you give me an idea about seprate urls for JSON API. I think It can solve my current problem in the best way. I just wanted to have single url for take any content, POST data or JSON data, but now I see it's goona be a trouble.

Comment: I mark your answer just for this hint with separating urls. Thank you.